# Trying to do angularjs tutorial on vagrant box, karma not working

Tags: node.js, angularjs, karma-jasmine

Basically got stuck at the first page: https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial after installing the files I changed karma.conf.js so it uses PhantomJS

```
browsers : ['PhantomJS'],
```

Installed PhantomJS:

```
[vagrant@localhost angular-phonecat]$ npm install phantomjs
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/phantomjs
//... a lot more
npm http 503 https://registry.npmjs.org/cryptiles
npm ERR! registry error parsing json
npm http 503 https://registry.npmjs.org/assert-plus/0.1.2
npm ERR! registry error parsing json
//... some more
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/cryptiles

> phantomjs@1.9.7-12 install /var/www/html/hosts/angulartest/angular-phonecat/node_modules/phantomjs
> node install.js

Download already available at /tmp/phantomjs/phantomjs-1.9.7-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2
Extracting tar contents (via spawned process)
Copying extracted folder /tmp/phantomjs/phantomjs-1.9.7-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2-extract-1404194867925/phantomjs-1.9.7-linux-x86_64 -> /var/www/html/hosts/angulartest/angular-phonecat/node_modules/phantomjs/lib/phantom
Writing location.js file
Done. Phantomjs binary available at /var/www/html/hosts/angulartest/angular-phonecat/node_modules/phantomjs/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs
phantomjs@1.9.7-12 node_modules/phantomjs
├── which@1.0.5
├── progress@1.1.7
├── rimraf@2.2.8
├── kew@0.1.7
├── ncp@0.4.2
├── mkdirp@0.3.5
├── adm-zip@0.2.1
├── request-progress@0.3.1 (throttleit@0.0.2)
├── npmconf@0.0.24 (inherits@1.0.0, once@1.1.1, osenv@0.0.3, ini@1.1.0, semver@1.1.4, nopt@2.2.1, config-chain@1.1.8)
└── request@2.36.0 (json-stringify-safe@5.0.0, forever-agent@0.5.2, qs@0.6.6, aws-sign2@0.5.0, oauth-sign@0.3.0, tunnel-agent@0.4.0, node-uuid@1.4.1, mime@1.2.11, tough-cookie@0.12.1, form-data@0.1.4, http-signature@0.10.0, hawk@1.0.0)
```

Then start the test

```
[vagrant@localhost angular-phonecat]$ npm test

> angular-phonecat@0.0.0 pretest /var/www/html/hosts/angulartest/angular-phonecat
> npm install


> phantomjs@1.9.7-12 install /var/www/html/hosts/angulartest/angular-phonecat/node_modules/phantomjs
> node install.js

Download already available at /tmp/phantomjs/phantomjs-1.9.7-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2
Extracting tar contents (via spawned process)
Copying extracted folder /tmp/phantomjs/phantomjs-1.9.7-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2-extract-1404195014386/phantomjs-1.9.7-linux-x86_64 -> /var/www/html/hosts/angulartest/angular-phonecat/node_modules/phantomjs/lib/phantom
Writing location.js file
Done. Phantomjs binary available at /var/www/html/hosts/angulartest/angular-phonecat/node_modules/phantomjs/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs

> angular-phonecat@0.0.0 postinstall /var/www/html/hosts/angulartest/angular-phonecat
> bower install


> angular-phonecat@0.0.0 test /var/www/html/hosts/angulartest/angular-phonecat
> karma start test/karma.conf.js

WARN [karma]: Port 9876 in use
WARN [karma]: Port 9877 in use
WARN [karma]: Port 9878 in use
WARN [karma]: Port 9879 in use
WARN [karma]: Port 9880 in use
WARN [karma]: Port 9881 in use
INFO [karma]: Karma v0.10.10 server started at http://localhost:9882/
WARN [launcher]: Can not load "PhantomJS", it is not registered!
  Perhaps you are missing some plugin?
```

Not sure what this means, it says phantomjs is both available and not available.

**[update]**

After installing karma-phantomjs-launcher (npm install karma-phantomjs-launcher) I had to change karma.conf.js:

```
browsers : ['PhantomJS'],

plugins : [
        'karma-phantomjs-launcher',
        'karma-jasmine'
        ],
```

Tests are running now.

Comment: Have you tried adding `karma-phantomjs-launcher` to your plugins-list?

Comment: Didn't your forget to install karma-phantomjs-launcher?

Comment: @AndreyShustariov Yes, that and changing the plugins in the karma config did the trick. Thank you and Ivarni

Comment: where you able to run protractor? if so, how, step by step please. I'm new to all these tools

Comment: @ChristopherFrancisco Sorry, I have not tried protractor yet.